# Concatenating Matrices

Tags: matlab

From what I am understanding about this section,concatenating matrices is when you combine two matrices into one. I have two matrices of the same size, but want to combine them into a third of a different size; I don't understand how or why this would be possible. The sample question I was given in below for reference.

"Given matrices A (75x75) and B (75x75) create matrix C with dimensions (75x150). Assign the number of rows and columns of C to variables named rows and cols using function size."

Comment: See e.g. [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html)

Comment: I am beginning to think I will never understand this stuff, it's been a couple of weeks and I am completely lost in trying to understand the concepts.

Comment: and [horzcat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html)

Comment: I guess where i am getting confused is the question says "Matrices A and B are provided by calling the load function - load (Question4.mat")

I entered 
C =load(Question4.mat")
rows = 75
cols = 150

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Or by simply doing `C = [A B]` → Which has the same functionality of the `C = horzcat(A,B)` function or `C = [A; B]` → Which has the same functionality of the `C = vertcat(A,B)` function. To return the number of row and columns you can use `[rows,cols] = size(C)`.

Comment: Visually you can think of this as stitching/gluing the two matrices together them side by side.

Answer (score 3):

The following will load variables from the mat file directly into the workspace using the variable names present in the mat file

```
load('Question4.mat')
```

Presumably this will load variables A and B into your workspace. This is apparently what is being asked of you.

The following will load variables from the mat file into a single struct variable called C where fieldnames of C will be the variable names from the mat file

```
C = load('Question4.mat')
```

This is *not* what is being asked of you. If you did this you would then have to get at the A and B variables with the syntax C.A and C.B, which isn't what is intended for the assignment.

Assuming you have the variables A and B in the workspace, you can typically concatenate them with the square brackets. Use a comma to concatenate them horizontally, and use a semi-colon to concatenate them vertically. E.g., try these two lines out and see what you get:

```
[A,B]
[A;B]
```

Once you have figured out how to get the proper C variable, just use the size( ) function with the two output option (see the section Dimension Lengths as Separate Arguments). See the doc for the size function here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html?searchHighlight=size&s_tid=srchtitle

Comment: OP specifically posted this in a comment to the original post.